# How to handle the bug about "Package epstopdf Warning: Drivers other than `pdftex' and `luatex' are not supported."

Tags: packages, algorithms

I want to write some pseudo code in LaTeX and it reports some error that I cannot debug.

I import the packages like this:

```latex
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,times,oneside,openright]{eeereport}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}

\title{Enhanced Ant-Colony Algorithm Based on Solving Trams-Route Problem   {}}
\subtitle{\\In Partial Fulfillment of the Requirements for the Degree of\\Bachelor of Science}
\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Calculate $y = x^n$}
\begin{algorithmic}
\REQUIRE $n \geq 0 \vee x \neq 0$
\ENSURE $y = x^n$
\STATE $y \leftarrow 1$
\IF{$n < 0$}
\STATE $X \leftarrow 1 / x$
\STATE $N \leftarrow -n$
\ELSE
\STATE $X \leftarrow x$
\STATE $N \leftarrow n$
\ENDIF
\WHILE{$N \neq 0$}
\IF{$N$ is even}
\STATE $X \leftarrow X \times X$
\STATE $N \leftarrow N / 2$
\ELSE[$N$ is odd]
\STATE $y \leftarrow y \times X$
\STATE $N \leftarrow N - 1$
\ENDIF
\ENDWHILE
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
....
```

And it reports error like this:

```
Package epstopdf Warning: Drivers other than `pdftex' and `luatex' are not supported.

)) (psfig.sty
psfig/tex 1.10-dvips
) (D:\latex\tex/latex/url\url.sty) (D:\latex\tex/latex/graphics\epsfig.sty)
(D:\latex\tex/latex/subfigure\subfigure.sty
****************************************
* Local config file subfigure.cfg used *
****************************************
(D:\latex\tex/latex/subfigure\subfigure.cfg))
(D:\latex\tex/latex/psfrag\psfrag.sty) (D:\latex\tex/latex/amsfonts\amssymb.sty
(D:\latex\tex/latex/amsfonts\amsfonts.sty)) (D:\latex\tex/latex/float\float.sty
) (D:\latex\tex/latex/algorithmicx\algpseudocode.sty
(D:\latex\tex/latex/base\ifthen.sty)
(D:\latex\tex/latex/algorithmicx\algorithmicx.sty
Document Style algorithmicx 1.2 - a greatly improved `algorithmic' style
)
Document Style - pseudocode environments for use with the `algorithmicx' style
) (D:\latex\tex/latex/algorithms\algorithm.sty)
(D:\latex\tex/latex/amsmath\amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(D:\latex\tex/latex/amsmath\amstext.sty (D:\latex\tex/latex/amsmath\amsgen.sty)
) (D:\latex\tex/latex/amsmath\amsbsy.sty)
(D:\latex\tex/latex/amsmath\amsopn.sty))
(D:\latex\tex/latex/multirow\multirow.sty) (D:\latex\tex/latex/tools\array.sty)
 (D:\latex\tex/latex/xstring\xstring.sty
(D:\latex\tex/generic/xstring\xstring.tex)))
(D:\latex\tex/latex/algorithms\algorithmic.sty

! LaTeX Error: Command \algorithmicindent already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX template Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.51 \newlength{\algorithmicindent}

?
```

How to fix the problem?

Comment: Why are you using a class that loads packages like psfig and epsfig that are deprecated since many years?

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer I download the temlate of latex from github. And I'm not sure how to add the packages.

Comment: You have the packages but you should not use them. psfig is from 1990 or so. Why are you using this template instead of e.g. a standard class like report?